# How to find out and replace a specified string with rules then write to the source file?

Tags: powershell

I have worked on a batch script with Powershell, it needs to be run with a schedule file and the contents as follows:

```
Server;Services;ContentPath;Status(Ready,Done,Disabled)
server1;servicename1;c:\test\;Ready
server2;servicename1,servername2;c:\test,d:\temp;Ready
```

The script will scan the file line by line. The retrieved content will be split by and pass into the function to do some health check.

However, I found that when a server fails to connect and needs to change `Ready` to `disabled` in the text, the text will be overwritten to only one current line. :-(

```
Get-Content -Path $PlayBook | where{$_ -match 'server1'} |%{$_.replace("Ready","Disable")} | Set-Content $PlayBook
```

So Is there anyway we can replace the specified content in the text according to the rule? Or should I convert the text to a CSV file , Maybe there are more methods and object we can use?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is `where{$_ -match 'server1'}` because this acts like a filter and is only passing the lines that match it to the next command in the pipeline.

pseudo code example:

```
import file | filter only lines containing 'server1' | replace text | export file
```

As the `filter` only matches a single line, only that single line is passed through the pipeline to the `replace`, and then also only a single line to `export file`.

You need to move the `match` condition inside the `foreach`... you are then looping through each item (line) and then modifying the item if it matches your criteria:

```
(Get-Content -Path $PlayBook) | foreach {
    if ($_ -match 'server1'){
        $_.replace("Ready","Disable")
    }
    else {
        $_ # send item to pipeline so it's passed to next step
    }
} | Set-Content $PlayBook
```

Comment: Hi James , i am appreciate for your advice. However after the code updated , I found that all content in original file has been deleted and left only one row . :-(  could you please help on it ?

Comment: Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).